# generate JSON data based on input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I would like to generate JSON data based on the following input fields:
name
uRL
where the JSON data output would look something like this:

```
{   
"items": [
    {
        "url": "content/San-Francisco/berkeleyCampanile.jpg",
        "name": "Image 1 name"
    },
    {
        "url": "content/San-Francisco/castro.jpg",
        "name": "Image 2 name"
    },
    {
        "url": "content/San-Francisco/Tenderloin.jpg",
        "name": "Image 3 name"
    }
]
}
```

How it works right now is that theres two input field, name and url, and users can add another set of name and url inputs by clicking on the add button as shown on the picture

[image]

What I want is that when the user hits on generate it output based on all of the input filled the json data as shown on the format above.

Below is the code:

```
<head>

      <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<fieldset id="buildyourform">
    <legend>test</legend>
</fieldset>
<input type="button" value="Add a field" class="add" id="add" />
<input type="button" value="Generate" class="add" id="preview" />&nbsp;

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
     var name = $("<input type=\"text\" \"id=\"name\"placeholder=\"Name of Neighborhood\"class=\"fieldname\" />");
       var url = $("<input type=\"text\"id=\"url\"placeholder=\"Paste here the URL of the Image\"class=\"fieldname\" />");


        var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\"class=\"remove\" value=\"Remove\" />");
        removeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
        fieldWrapper.append(name);
                fieldWrapper.append(url);

        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
        $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
    });

});

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Update:

```
<html>
<head>

      <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="myform">
<fieldset id="jsonBuilder">
    <legend id="legendHead">Neighboorhood Creation</legend>
</fieldset>
<input type="button" value="Add a field" class="add" id="add" />
<input type="submit" value="generate" class="add">
</form>

<script>

 function showValues() {
 var frm = $('#myform');
 var data = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());
}
</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
        var name = $("<input type=\"text\" \"id=\"name\"placeholder=\"Name of Neighborhood\"class=\"fieldname\" />");
           var url = $("<input type=\"text\"id=\"url\"placeholder=\"Paste here the URL of the Image\"class=\"fieldname\" />");

        var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\"class=\"remove\" value=\"Remove\" />");
        removeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
        fieldWrapper.append(name);
                fieldWrapper.append(url);

        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
        $("#jsonBuilder").append(fieldWrapper);
    });

});

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If possible add id to your input filed also

Comment: allow me to clarify. My question is I have a set of inputs, how do I convert them into JSON data. where I have a group set of inputs (name, url), and I want each pair to be output as a json data all together and displayed to the user. AN example of a json data being output is here http://jsfiddle.net/sxGtM/3/ but this is based on a html form, I don't have a form just inputs

Comment: As suggested, I have added an ID to each input, known as name and url respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A suggestion:

1. same ids are getting repeated so i changed it to class.

All you need is this:

```
  $('#preview').click(function(){
    var o = {"items":[]}; // create an object with key items to hold array
    $('.fieldwrapper').each(function(){ // loop in to the input's wrapper
      var obj = {
        url :  $(this).find('.url').val(), // place the url in a new object
        name : $(this).find('.name').val() // place the name in a new object
      };
      o.items.push(obj); // push in the "o" object created
    });
    $('#console').text(JSON.stringify(o)); // strigify to show
  });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function() {
    var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
    var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
    var name = $("<input type=\"text\" \" placeholder=\"Name of Neighborhood\"class=\"name fieldname\" />");
    var url = $("<input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Paste here the URL of the Image\"class=\"url fieldname\" />");


    var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\"class=\"remove\" value=\"Remove\" />");
    removeButton.click(function() {
      $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    fieldWrapper.append(name);
    fieldWrapper.append(url);

    fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
    $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
  });
  
  $('#preview').click(function(){
  
    var o = {"items":[]}; // create an object with key items to hold array
    
    $('.fieldwrapper').each(function(){ // loop in to the input's wrapper
      var obj = {
        url :  $(this).find('.url').val(), // place the url in a new object
        name : $(this).find('.name').val() // place the name in a new object
      };
        o.items.push(obj); // push in the "o" object created
    });
    
    $('#console').text(JSON.stringify(o)); // strigify to show
    
  });
  

});
```

```css
#console {
  background: #c5c5c5;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset id="buildyourform">
  <legend>test</legend>
</fieldset>
<input type="button" value="Add a field" class="add" id="add" />
<input type="button" value="Generate" class="add" id="preview" />&nbsp;
<div id='console'></div>
```

Comment: very well written. Thank you. One minor suggestion, is there any way the output of the json could slightly be better formatted, where instead being all cramped in one line, its well spaced out. This just makes it cleaner and easier for copy and pastinfg

Comment: @JonathanEtienne for that i use to go to http://pro.jsonlint.com/ to check i json is valid and it formats it perfectly.

Comment: thank you that editor is greatly helpful, and I included it as an iframe in my site. just one last question, how could I set so that when a user hits submit button at the button, it triggers them to save the json file into their computer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JQuery **.serializeArray()** method, here's the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/)
Here's an example:

```
var json = $('#form').serializeArray();
```

---

If you don't want to add the **form** tag to your code, here's a script that creates the JSON from your current form, [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2dydedpo/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#add").click(function() {
    var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
    var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
    var name = $("<input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Name of Neighborhood\"class=\"fieldname\" name=\"name\" />");
       var url = $("<input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Paste here the URL of the Image\"class=\"fieldname\" name=\"url\" />");

    var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\"class=\"remove\" value=\"Remove\" />");
    removeButton.click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    fieldWrapper.append(name);
            fieldWrapper.append(url);

    fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
    $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
});
$('#preview').click(function(){
    var json = {};
    json.items = [];
    $('.fieldwrapper').each(function(e){
        var obj = {};
        obj.name = $(this).find('input[name=name]').val();
        obj.url = $(this).find('input[name=url]').val();
        json.items.push(obj);            
    });

    console.log(json);
});


});
```

Comment: this seems to be a comment.

Comment: thanks for your response. my concern is that I am not using a form, rather a set of inputs

Comment: If you don't want to add the **form** tag to your html, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a JSFiddle for your guidance. Please take a look.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DivakarDass/kkkdwg2h/1/)

```js
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    var items = {};
  items["items"] = $( this ).serializeArray();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" name="url" />
<input type="text" name="image" />
<input type="text" name="url" />
<input type="text" name="image" />
    <button class="generate" type="submit" id="generate">Generate</button>
</form>
```

Comment: you need JSON.stringify for make proper json object as per my knowledge

Comment: Going ahead please include your code into the answer. I have done it for now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one without the `form` demo@[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/30x9ckpy/1/)

```
$("#preview").click(function() {
    var arr = {};
    arr.items = [];

    $(".fieldwrapper").each(function() {
        var entry = {}
        var neighborhood = $(this).find("input[name='neighborhood']").val();            
        var url = $(this).find("input[name='url']").val();
        entry["url"] = url;
        entry["name"] = neighborhood;
        arr.items.push(entry);
    });
    alert (JSON.stringify(arr, null, 4));
});
```

P.S. I have added name attributes to your input elements.

Answer (score 0):

With Json Indentation

**html**

```
<fieldset id="buildyourform">
    <legend>test</legend>
</fieldset>
<input type="button" value="Add a field" class="add" id="add" />
<input type="button" value="Generate" class="add" id="preview" />&nbsp;
<pre id="json"></pre>
```

**Javascript**

```
var items = {'items':[]}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
     var name = $("<input type=\"text\" \"class=\"name\"placeholder=\"Name of Neighborhood\"class=\"fieldname\" />");
       var url = $("<input type=\"text\"class=\"url\"placeholder=\"Paste here the URL of the Image\"class=\"fieldname\" />");


        var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\"class=\"remove\" value=\"Remove\" />");
        removeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
        fieldWrapper.append(name);
                fieldWrapper.append(url);

        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
        $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
    });
    $('#preview').on('click',function(){
        $('.fieldwrapper').each(function(){
            items.items.push({'url':$(this).find('.url').val(),'name':$(this).find('.fieldname').val()});
});
document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(items, undefined, 2);
    });
});
```

here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ob43hwdu/1/)

Comment: thank you for the fiddle just one minor question, how could I set so that when a user hits submit button at the button, it triggers them to save the json file into their computer